# Failed to resolve: com.osbcp.cssparser:cssparser:1.5 HtmlSpanner-NightWhistler

Tags: android, android-studio, epub, epublib

I integrated **HtmlSpanner** into my Android application. I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to resolve: com.osbcp.cssparser:cssparser:1.5.

How do I solve this error?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 5):

This library is not in the standard `Maven` repository, that `Gradle` uses to resolve dependencies.

You should add the following repository address to your `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://repo.pageturner-reader.org"
    }
}
```

Comment: I follow your instruction but i get the same error nothing to happen

Comment: Have you synced project with Gradle and rebuild it?
Have you put it above dependencies?

Comment: yes I put it above dependencies.// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://repo.pageturner-reader.org"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

Comment: Do you have this in `app/build.gradle` file: `compile 'com.osbcp.cssparser:cssparser:1.5'` ?

Comment: I have  compile files('libs/cssparser-1.5.jar') in build.gradle(app)

Comment: i need a file please suggest that link

Comment: You want this? http://repo.pageturner-reader.org/com/osbcp/cssparser/cssparser/1.5/

Comment: I add that jar file in my application but i got the same error

Comment: give a demo for integrating Html Spanner

Comment: I had tried by adding this maven url but still I got this error, org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'http://repo.pageturner-reader.org/com/highsoft/highcharts/highcharts/6.1.4/highcharts-6.1.4.pom'. Received status code 403 from server

Answer (score 2):

If somebody is still looking, this lib or its analogue is in
[maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.osbcp/cssparser?repo=jcenter)

So you can just add dependency to build.gradle:

```
 implementation 'com.osbcp:cssparser:1.7'
```

If you also need HTMLCleaner dependency, you can also find it in the [standard repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner/htmlcleaner)

And add as a dependency to build.gradle like this:

```
implementation 'net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:2.26'
```