# Gradle sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly

Tags: android, highcharts, build.gradle

When I run project I got gradle sync failed error.

Here are the error:
org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'http://repo.pageturner-reader.org/com/highsoft/highcharts/highcharts/6.1.4/highcharts-6.1.4.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden<35 Internal calls>

Below is full error message:

```
    Executing tasks: [assembleDebug]

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.osbcp.cssparser:cssparser:1.5.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Could not resolve com.osbcp.cssparser:cssparser:1.5.
      > Could not get resource 'http://repo.pageturner-reader.org/com/osbcp/cssparser/cssparser/1.5/cssparser-1.5.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'http://repo.pageturner-reader.org/com/osbcp/cssparser/cssparser/1.5/cssparser-1.5.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
```

My Top-level build file are

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://highsoft.bintray.com/Highcharts"}
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Here is my app level build.gradle file content.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven {
            url "http://repo.pageturner-reader.org"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://highsoft.bintray.com/Highcharts"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: https://github.com/corgrath/osbcp-css-parser ...had been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you have mentioned is not in detail. To check the error in detail, click on the **Gradle** tab on the right side -> **app** -> double click on **assembleDebug**.

Comment: I have given a full message as per your guideline

Comment: The **pageturner cssparser**  project library you have used has been closed itseems, hence the requesting url has not fetched and so 403 Error.

Comment: Refer this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38970863/failed-to-resolve-com-osbcp-cssparsercssparser1-5-htmlspanner-nightwhistler] it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please also provide the app level build.gradle, might have to do with the repository/dependency config there.

Comment: I have given app level build.gradle file content in question.